# Unable to print output in a loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, cout

I'm still in learning phase in C++ and I encountered this problem... please help me out::
i want to print these values..

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int count_x=0, count_o=0, count_=0;
        char a[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                cin>>a[i][j];
                if(a[i][j]=='X') count_x++;
                if(a[i][j]=='O') count_o++;
                if(a[i][j]=='_') count_++;
              }
        }
        cout<<count_x<<" "<<count_o<<endl;
     }`
      return 0;``
  }
```

Comment: What does it do or not do that it shouldn't do or should do?

Comment: this program accepts input from user as character and stores it in a 2d array of 3x3 then it  counts the occurrence of  'O' ,   'X' ,and  '_'  in the provided input  and prints the output.

Comment: That's what you want it to do or that's what is currently happening? Please clarify exactly what result you are trying to get from your code and what you're getting instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work... the only problem is when more data than the requested if provided.

This problem can be solved in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.clear();
    while(t--){
        int count_x=0, count_o=0, count_=0;
        char a[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                cin>>a[i][j];
                if(a[i][j]=='X') count_x++;
                if(a[i][j]=='O') count_o++;
                if(a[i][j]=='_') count_++;
              }
        }
        cout<<count_x<<" "<<count_o<<endl;
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin.clear();
     }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ..but this still doesn't gives the desired output:   suppose my input is.... OOX
                 XXO
                 O_O
the output should be : 4  5

Comment: Why 4 5? The sequence which you indicated has 3 X and 5 O. Maybe you can explain me what is needed then...

Comment: I'm so sorry buddy its actually typing mistake ..its 3 5